# differences between ModelSerializer.update() and ModelViewSet.update()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I found both `ModelSerializer` and `ModelViewSet` have `update()` method, and I think both are almost same. Is that correct ?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # update of model instances
        instance.save()
        return instance


class FooModelAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = my_queryset

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # updateds model instances and save
        return Response("OK")
```

In the above snippet, Can I use either ModelSerializer or ModelViewSet without another for updating model instance ?

Answer (score 4):

If you put the update() method in a view, it is bind to the view itself; meaning that you can only use it in a specific url. 
However, if you use it in the serializer, you can use it persistently throughout your application's views.